# specify temp folder for msi extracted files used for installation

Tags: virtualization, windows-installer, files, msi

I was recently installing [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=71deb800-c591-4f97-a900-bea146e4fae1&displaylang=en) to create my build server on a VM (Windows 2003 R2 Std), I was wondering that it would be nice to specify the temporary folder for the files being extracted by MSI for use during the installation. 
 This should ideally work for any MSIs.

I have some more virtual hard disks I have attached to this VMs, to point the temporary folder for MSI to one of these virtual hard disks would be quite productive since I can remove/discard this virtual hard disk later.

Compacting the C drive VHD is a pain, and does not always reclaim space correctly.

I tried changing the %temp% and tmp environment variable with no effect? Or is there any concrete/alternative solution to this type of problem?

**References:**
[TempFolder Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372067(VS.85).aspx) ??
 
[Windows Installer Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer)

Comment: Did you change your %TEMP% variable or the system one? I know this works for XP if you set the system variable.

Comment: @John, System Properties --> Environmental Variables...

Comment: on that dialog the upper part is for your personal variables and the bottom part is for the system ones. If setting the system variable hasn't worked try setting your personal one (create it if necessary) and see if that gives you the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

For .Net 4.0 or higher, the command is: `dotNetinstaller.exe /x:c:\destination_folder /q`

For .Net 3.5 or older, the command *should* be: `dotNetinstaller.exe /T:c:\destination_folder /q`